# Matlab radial gradient image

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to create a radial gradient image to look like the following using Matlab. The image needs to be of size 640*640*3 as I have to blend it with another image of that size. I have written the following code but the image that prints out is simply a grey circle on a black background with no fading around the edges.

```
p = zeros(640,640,3);
for i=1:640
    for j=1:640
        d = sqrt((i-320)^2+(j-320)^2);
        if d < 640/3
            p(i,j,:) = .5;
        elseif d > 1280/3
            p(i,j,:) = 0;
        else
            p(i,j,:) = (1 + cos(3*pi)*(d-640/3))/4;
        end
    end
end
imshow(p);
```

[image: radial gradient image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
p(i,j,:) = (1 + cos(3*pi)*(d-640/3))/4;
```

to

```
p(i,j,:) = .5-( (.5-0)*(d-640/3)/(640/3)) ;
```

This is an example of linear interpolation, where the grey value from the inner rim drops linearly to the background.

You can try other equations to have different kinds of gradient fading!

Answer (score 0):

If you look more closely on your third case (which by the way should be a simple else instead of elseif), you can see that you have

```
= (1 + cos(3*pi))*...
```

Since cos(3*pi) = -1, this will always be 0, thus making all pixels within that range black. I assume that you would want a "d" in there somewhere.

Comment: There was an error in the code there. It was meant to be 

    `p(i,j,:) = (1 + cos(3*pi)*(d-640/3))/4;` @rasan076